# issues running a script with sudo commands inside

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a script without ask for root password.
So i have a script.sh with several sudo commands inside and I've modified the file sudoers with "sudo visudo" to be able to run the script without ask for root password :

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user/script.sh

as well I've change the user and group of my script (sudo chown root.root script.sh) and change the as well (`sudo chmod 777 script.sh`)
, but always that I try to run my script it ask for root password, and I don't idea what can it be

Note: I tried as well change this >
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user/script.sh ,
and the user,group to (user) and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Hope this helps; be sure to follow it to the letter - http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password

Answer (score 1):

remove all `sudo` commands in your script. Just put the below lines at the beginning of your script

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Aborting: run as root user!"
    exit 1
fi

#... your program
```

This makes the whole script to be run with super user. and none of the commands in your script needs sudo prefix.

Comment: with you code when try to run the script with your cide doesnt allow me run it, and when i remove the code the command inside in the script show me the error : sed: can't read /etc/sudoers: Permission denied,  i've remove all sudo commands inside

Comment: Its not allowing you to run because, Initially you are asking the user to run your script with super user privilage. i.e. if your script file is test.sh and needs sudo privilege to run few commands. By adding the given lines, instead of `./test.sh` , the script has to be run with `sudo ./test.sh` and provide the password initially.

Comment: yes, but the thing is that i need to run this script at startup on ubuntu without that the user run the script , for that reason i've added it to sudoers file, but it doesnt works yet

Comment: Oh! at startup, okay check this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: the link works, it execute any script at startup, but it has issues when the script has sudo commands inside or any command that needs to be run as sudo